# Constantly launching multiprocessing Processes in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a relatively CPU heavy function that I've been running as a thread in a package I have.  Since it's CPU heavy I want to move it to a `multiprocessing` process.  The nature of this function is such that it will be called very often.  Is this a fair / safe use for `multiprocessing`?

An alternative would be to launch the function with multiprocessing and have it run continually, and accept input from somewhere, though I am new to the `multiprocessing` module and am not sure if I can feed one of its processes data while it's running.

Comment: Exactly how CPU heavy is it, and why, might I ask?

Comment: @Thecheater887 - Not extremely CPU heavy, it does some fairly basic math.  Since it's being run alongside several other threads, and since it does its job repeatedly, I've decided to try multiprocessing.

Comment: One of the better things to do in this case is multithread each process, if that is possible. A computer running 1000 5-line processes is going to be MUCH more power-hungry than a computer running 1 5000-line process. Again, I don't know what, why, and when you are trying to achieve your goal, but, the most efficient would be said method, if possible.

Comment: The very first thing to do is to profile your code to find out where it is actually spending all of the time, if it is a blocking call - i.e. the code cannot proceed without the result then multiprocessing just adds complexity and overhead. Then look to see if you have all of the data available long before the call to it - in that case you could start the calculation as soon as you have the data then fetch/wait for the result or better yet carry on with some other work until it is ready.